# I doubt myself as a writer. Is there anything I can do to better my writing?

Tags: creative-writing, fiction, prose

Over the years I have fallen in love with writing narratives.  I found the passion when I began to experiment with emotes as a teenager on a Peer-2-Peer program used to download music.  Some of the good folks around here might have heard of it.  It was called Napster.  As time went on I joined communities in other programs and websites and I found an aspect of writing stories that had an additional competitive feature.  A lot of people know it generally as role-play writing.  Communities that focus on that type of cooperative story-telling refer to it as T1(Type One), a specific branch of role-playing.  Each writer attempts to write turn based narratives where their character battles the other (s) until defeat.

I explain these details to give a possible insight on the first narrative I have posted below.  The second narrative is a piece of cooperative scene I was asked to introduce my character and participate in.

I believe my problem is in this competitive field of writing I have engaged in for over a decade.  It is cutthroat most of the time with condescending explanations and barely any trace of support between beginners and veterans alike.  I am considered a bad writer by some and a good writer by others.  The negative feedback has left the most impression.  I'm older now and can handle being told what I'm doing wrong.  I've never thought to seek advice or criticism from actual writing communities to further my own writing ability, but I feel it is necessary in order to advance.  I dream of writing a book.  I also feel I require validation in order to begin my literary journey.  What are some ways I can improve my writing?

First narrative

> A vermillion streak bolted through the vast vacuum of outer-space as
> it traveled with purpose, trailing radiant scintillation of red hued
> particles in its comet-like wake.  Its direction headed to a
> pinpointed location in the depths of this universe, having been
> spontaneously made aware of a blossomed phenomenon set across the
> connected cosmos.  A point of prowess inviting a challenge was never
> mistaken, especially by an individual that always responded to these
> specific signals.  Countless sources of starlight flit by, their glows
> stretched into lined bands of illumination as he tore past them in his
> teleportation towards what was referred to as The Dimensional Gate.
>
> The emblazoned levin ceased its meteoric speed as space no longer
> dilated around his extramundane motion.  An anticipated halt of
> movement had positioned him not close, but not far from the entity
> that had seemingly invaded this realm with a readied stock of
> malicious intent.  They were simultaneously present in each other’s
> line of sight, near enough to distinguish details of one another’s
> physical appearance such as the colors of one’s skin and hair, if
> openly revealed, and the style of attire they outfitted themselves in.
>
> He wore a funeral suit of seemingly black velvet, decorated in
> numerous sown reparations from prior tears in the material.  Stitching
> along suit displayed a visual duality of meticulousness and savagery,
> threading an off color to the original fabric.  Glossy dress shoes
> slightly mirrored the ambient cosmic rays that naturally bled towards
> where they were, adding to the similar toned slacks, dress-shirt, and
> suit-coat of charcoal shade.  In stark contrast, deathly guise of the
> pallid psychomask had been donned, absent entirely of any expressional
> features along its reflective porcelain-like surface - save for the
> dual openings for gaze to peer through.  Ebon tresses of hair hung
> amongst artificial countenance as everything loosened 'pon him floated
> in a gravity-less subtlety.
>
> Alabaster flesh of neck and gloveless hands were exposed to the harsh
> environment of space, and though he was conscious of the temperature
> and lack of any pressure in the surrounding emptiness, his inhabited
> corpse acquired no drawbacks or obstacles that hindered his non-linear
> existence.  He did not care, nor had reason to.  It did not bother him
> to be in a cruel and indifferent atmosphere that was incapable of
> supplying or promoting organic growth.  Space offered in a bizarre
> comfort an intimacy he was already accustomed to, reminding him of
> places much more darker and dangerous beyond the threshold of known
> corporeality.  In his right dominant hand he had in grasp the slim
> black sword Angelslayer, held with a relaxed, comfortable grip.
>
> Despite being merely a traveling guest to this Multiversal quadrant,
> he answered the call as if he were an occupying resident, appearing
> promptly after only moments of the beacon being initialized.  A
> passive, colorless occurrence had exploded from his form as it burst
> outwards from him spherically at breakneck speed, him being the
> epicenter.  It swept from where he was unto multiple kilometers in a
> casual range, instantaneously filling the abundant empty-space around
> him with his projected sensory-self.  This was his awareness filling
> the surrounding area with a physically and metaphysically harmless
> force, yet could prove otherwise if his outer-body-awareness were
> applied with tact and strategy.  The immediate vicinity, a few feet
> directly around him, was confined in his influential will, capturing
> the area in his sovereignty.

Second Narrative

> Sickly pallid complexion leant forward from a pitch shade.  Neck
> adorned with yellow scarf moved from deep black, followed by
> shoulders, arms, and the rest of his mercenary garbed self.  From the
> deep shadow he literally pushed himself with gloved hands, those faded
> looking almond hues stared unblinking at the other nearby.  Eyes
> sought figure, mind was assessing and sudden rush of unseen wind burst
> in all directions; outer-body-awareness triggered and expanded.
> “Symphonia.  Leisure stroll?” One of the original three, code name
> still active even in her Deadcorps career, though rarely did they
> resort to that form of identification.  Raiken was different, though,
> wasn’t he? Back then it was the three of them.  Orchestratus, Sonatus,
> and Symphonia.  They were a killing wind that swept effortlessly
> across their lands.  Never one or the other -- always all three at
> once.  After leaving their destroyed home, they gave everything they
> came across death or hell.  Sometimes both. When she died, it ushered
> them into a new age -- though deep down the two brothers were never
> the same.  Sonatus thrived in his ascendancy whilst Orchestratus
> roamed.  It wasn’t till the compound was rebuilt and they made it
> their home did things seem slightly how they should be. Things weren't
> ever truly the same, and Raiken couldn’t help himself from pulling kin
> back from oblivion; if any chance that family could be brought back,
> especially members of this one, he was going to attempt it
> wholeheartedly. Reconstructed bodies, spiritual defibrillator to force
> a momentary spark of life that could possibly flourish instead of
> fade.   Success came with a price however.  Zaihara Tainingen, also
> known as Symphonia just wasn’t how she was when alive.  Before she was
> killed. Before she was resurrected in the lab back at the compound.
> Maybe she was still getting used to being back? He wondered what she
> saw when completely dead; morbid intrigue didn't expose itself
> nevertheless.  That wasn't something you asked your sister.

I deeply apologize if this isn't material allowed to ask, or if I incorrectly used the format on the site.  This is my first time exposing my writing outside those little known communities.

Comment: Go to your library and start checking out the books on writing. The genre doesn't matter. They all have lessons to share.

Comment: Thank you Steve.  Couldn't I possibly find it online?  I hope that is an adequate alternative.

Comment: Hi. We don't do critiques here, but I offer 2 observations: 1. **do not look for validation in anonymous strangers online.** Keep hobby friends at a respectful distance. Competitors are not your friends. 2. You have nice wordflow, Van Gogh swirls. You're ready for *structure*: plot, character arc, POV, conflict – tricks to hook the reader and focus them through a longer work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Read**

Read everything you can get your hands on, especially your chosen writing genre and especially of authors you find yourself wanting to emulate but the more you read the better you will get as a writer. Also write, lots, ignore issues like punctuation, and spelling, and get words on the page. Go back and edit things later to see what you're doing well and what you need to work on. Don't worry too much about correcting your early material though, you'll look back at those pieces and lament their manifold inadequacies regardless. Keep the material though, some of the concepts and even dialogue may come in handy later.